# .click() not working in WordPress Plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm basically developing a plugin that generates table rows dynamically to display content on a defined page, when generating I want it to display a **button** on each row that actives an **Ajax** request when clicked, I've tried appending an **ID** and doing the jQuery onClick to perform this, yet it's not showing my test `alert()`

Here's the **jQuery** code I'm using :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#submit").click(function(event) {

            //Stop the form processing
        event.preventDefault();

            //Get the username value
        var Username = jQuery('#username').val();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            crossDomain: true,
            url: apiURL + "video/" + Username + "/views/",
            success: function(data) {
                Parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                jQuery.each(Parsed.user_media, function(i,v){
                    jQuery("#results").append("<tr><td><button type='submit' id='addtoPlaylist'>Add to Playlist</button></td></tr>");
                });
            },
        });

    });

    jQuery("#addtoPlaylist").click(function(event) {
        alert('Working!');
    });
});
```

Everything is working perfect as such as the **Ajax** calls and returning the table rows, It's just when I'm trying to utilise the `.click()` based on the `<button></button>` it just doesn't seem to activate nor throw any errors into console.

Comment: Can you show your html?

Comment: Use event delegation for that :

Comment: Does `#addtoPlaylist` element exist? If it is generated by ajax request then jQuery won't bind an event as on document:ready there is no element to bind to. Use `delegate` in that case

Comment: Quick question: shouldn't `<button></button>` be `<input type="submit" .../>`

Comment: @Tikkes No - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery("#results").on("click", "#addtoPlaylist", function(event) {
    alert('Working!');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

That's happened because you're adding link listen at document ready. At this time you're ajax call hasn't fired yet and the element don't exist in page.
You must create a separate function and call it in ajax return statement.
Notice that different buttons must have different ids.

The soluiton should been somethingh like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery("#submit").click(function(event) {

        //Stop the form processing
    event.preventDefault();

    var addtoPlaylist = function(){
         alert('Working!');
    }



        //Get the username value
    var Username = jQuery('#username').val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        url: apiURL + "video/" + Username + "/views/",
        success: function(data) {
            Parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            jQuery.each(Parsed.user_media, function(i,v){
                jQuery("#results").append("<tr><td><button type='submit' id='addtoPlaylist'>Add to Playlist</button></td></tr>");
                 jQuery("#addtoPlaylist").click(function(event) {
                          addtoPlaylist();
                  });
            });
        },
    });

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for generated elements:

```
$("#results").on('click','#addtoPlaylist',function(){
   alert('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#addtoPlaylist").on('click',function(event) {
        alert('Working!');
    });
```

Comment: Tested but to no avail, it's not throwing any alert or adding any errors to console, not sure why

Answer (score 0):

i prefer to use jQuery.delegate on future elements.

```
jQuery("body").delegate("#addtoPlaylist","click",function () {
    alert("delegate works fine!");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest not using delegated event handlers, but instead create the elements the proper way with jQuery :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#submit").closest('form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var Username = $('#username').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            crossDomain: true,
            url: apiURL + "video/" + Username + "/views/"
        }).done(function(data) {
            var Parsed = $.parseJSON(data);

            $.each(Parsed.user_media, function(i,v){
                var tr  = $('<tr />'),
                    td  = $('<td />'),
                    btn = $('<button />', {type:'submit',
                                           id  :'addtoPlaylist',
                                           text:'Add to Playlis',
                                           on:{
                                               click: function() {
                                                   alert('Working');
                                               }
                                           }
                           });

                $("#results").append( tr.append(tr.append(button)) );
            });
        });
    });
});
```

and note that you are appending multiple elements with the same ID.